# How to drop a view in Phoenix

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I created a Phoenix view `company1:USERS` for an existing HBase table. Namespace is `company1` and table name is `USERS`. I don't have Phoenix table mapped to the existing Hbase table.

```
CREATE VIEW "company1:USERS" ( pk VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, CF.USERNAME VARCHAR, CF.FULLNAME VARCHAR );
```

This `create` statement works fine. Now I want to drop it using this command: `DROP VIEW "company1:USERS"`, but it gives me an error:

```
SQL Error [1012] [42M03]: ERROR 1012 (42M03): Table undefined. tableName=company1:USERS
  org.apache.phoenix.schema.TableNotFoundException: ERROR 1012 (42M03): Table undefined. tableName=company1:USERS
```

Same goes for the following delete statements:

- `DROP VIEW "company1.USERS"`
- `DROP VIEW company1:USERS`
- `DROP VIEW company1.USERS`

Library used: `phoenix-core-4.8.0-HBase-1.1`

Any idea how to drop a Phoenix view with namespace?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this by deleting from Phoenix `SYSTEM` tables:

```
DELETE FROM SYSTEM."STATS" WHERE PHYSICAL_NAME = 'company1:USERS';
DELETE FROM SYSTEM."CATALOG" WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'company1:USERS';
```

Comment: Is there any method to drop view more graceful ? delete from system table seems rude.